# converting GMT to stftime using python

Tags: python

I want to convert `Wed, 14 Mar 2018 07:30:00 GMT` to **2018/03/14** in python. I am getting `unicode object has no attribute strftime` error. Someone help me.

Comment: please try to do by yourself before posting it here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Pradam,but i have asked question after i tried..

Comment: if you have tried please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_given = 'Wed, 14 Mar 2018 07:30:00 GMT'
datetime.strptime(date_given, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

You can read up below links for more details:

- Python documentation for `strptime`: [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- Python documentation for `strftime`: [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)